# Add and Remove Ad-Code dynamically in DIV with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I want to have **ad code** on sidebar on Desktop View, but when we resize it to Mobile View or when it is opened it on Mobile View, Ad Code should be removed.

What I have tried is as follows:

```
if($(window).width() > 479 )
    {
        $('.reccommended_box').text(
                '<div class="sidebar-ad">'
                + {!! $domain->code4 !!}
                +'</div>'
        );
    }else
    {
        $('.sidebar-ad').remove();
    }

$(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() <= 479 )
        {
            $('.sidebar-ad').remove();
        }else
        {
            $('.reccommended_box').text(
                    '<div class="sidebar-ad">'
                    + '{!! $domain->code4 !!}'
                    +'</div>'
            );
        }
    });
```

Where **{!! $domain->code4 !!}** is Dynamic Ad code coming from the Database.
Sidebar is as follows:

```
<div class="reccommended_box">
     <span class="sidebar-ad">

     </span>
</div>
```

The Code is being displayed, but not working properly.

Format of Ad code is as follows:

```
<div id="taboola-right-rail-article-thumbnails"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window._taboola = window._taboola || [];
  _taboola.push({
    mode: 'thumbnails-rr',
    container: 'taboola-right-rail-article-thumbnails',
    placement: 'Right Rail Article Thumbnails',
    target_type: 'mix'
  });
</script>
<div id="contentad192237"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(d) {
        var params =
        {
            id: "xxx",
            d:  "xxx",
            wid: "xxx",
            cb: (new Date()).getTime()
        };

        var qs=[];
        for(var key in params) qs.push(key+'='+encodeURIComponent(params[key]));
        var s = d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;
        var p = 'https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http';
        s.src = p + "://api.content.ad/Scripts/widget2.aspx?" + qs.join('&');
        d.getElementById("contentad192237").appendChild(s);
    })(document);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 480px) {
    .sidebar-ad {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I knew this, but I just don't want to hide, but want to remove that code :). Display none will hide the DIV obviously, but won't remove it :). Thank you for your help